# Pig script join multiple keys with or

Tags: join, apache-pig

Hi I have been trying to run this piece of pig script.

```
    meddata = join meddata by (icddiag1 or icddiag2) left outer, codes by code;
```

with the intent of joining the meddata file if icddiag1 matches codes or if icddiag2 matches codes. I know I can join multiple times and do an unioin, but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: easy but not very scalable is a CROSS / FILTER sequence

Comment: join + union + join is better than cross join + filter.